How can I add icons to the Firefox context menu?
On the left side of the "bookmark context menu" there would be enough space for symbols. I'd like to have a scissor-icon for the cut feature, a two-pages-icon for the copy feature, a bin icon for the delete feature and so on. Is there an add-on or a CSS snippet for putting those icons there?


Thanks to @MC10 the following is what I now use with the pictures downloaded for it to also work in an offline environment.

    #placesContext_sortBy\:name::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/sort.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_show_folder\:info::before,
    #placesContext_show_bookmark\:info::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/edit.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_deleteFolder::before,
    #placesContext_deleteBookmark::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/delete.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_deleteFolder,
    #placesContext_deleteBookmark {
        font-weight:700 !important;
        color:#d70022 !important; 
    }

    #placesContext_cut::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/cut.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_copy::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/copy.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_paste_group::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/paste.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_new\:bookmark::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/plus.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    #placesContext_new\:folder::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/folder-add.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }
    
    #placesContext_new\:separator::before {
        content: url('file://C:/Users/User/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/assets/subtract.svg');
        width: 16px;
        padding-right: 1em;
        filter: invert(1);
    }


This can be done through userChrome.css. If you have links to the icons you intend to use, I can create the CSS for you.

Thanks for your quick answer. I just thought of the icons used in Firefox itself, to match the style. The following link has a list of all the default icons ( https://acorn.firefox.com/latest/styles/iconography-q7JqGl5H ). There is a delete, edit, rename (cursor-text), folder-add, plus and more. A CSS snippet to even be able to set/add one of those icons would already be a great starting point for me.

You can target the specific bookmark context menu entries by their id's. Add this to your userChrome.css.
#placesContext_show_bookmark\:info::before {
    content: url('https://studio-assets.supernova.io/design-systems/18795/1d87c42a-ed73-4853-a63f-66790a98092c.svg');
    width: 16px;
    filter: invert(1);
}

#placesContext_deleteBookmark::before {
    content: url('https://studio-assets.supernova.io/design-systems/18795/55b7a498-6916-4cd2-933e-c65358fb25f9.svg');
    width: 16px;
    filter: invert(1);
}

#placesContext_cut::before {
    content: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/master/current/image/icons_fx88/edit_cut.svg');
    width: 16px;
    filter: invert(1);
}

#placesContext_copy::before {
    content: url('https://studio-assets.supernova.io/design-systems/18795/5606b820-8564-4f25-b496-232b38c2a518.svg');
    width: 16px;
    filter: invert(1);
}

#placesContext_paste_group::before {
    content: url('https://studio-assets.supernova.io/design-systems/18795/8bf13abb-e206-4717-bf33-5169f7e388d0.svg');
    width: 16px;
    filter: invert(1);
}


I inverted the colors since the icons were black and hard to see. If you are not using dark mode or prefer black icons, just remove the filter property.
Unfortunately they did not have a cut icon, so I found an alternative.

Thanks for the CSS snippet. One question though. Where did you get the CSS IDs from? (#placesContext_copy, etc.) Sadly, I can't really find a good documentation on that. I'd be especially interested in the ID for the 'Sort by Name' entry.

@doej1367 You can use the Browser Toolbox in Firefox to inspect the UI elements.

You can also find them here: https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/master/browser/components/places/content/placesContextMenu.inc.xhtml
